# Checking a property of a closed vector subspace of $L^1$.

Tags: lp-spaces

Based on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3834558/if-x-subset-l1-is-a-closed-vector-space-and-x-subset-bigcup-1p-leq-infty) question, I asked myself the following:

Let $\Omega=(0,1)$ and let
$X=\overline{\text{span}\{x^{1/n-1}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}},$
where the closure is taken in $L^1(0,1)$. Does $X$ satisfy the conditions for the claim in the linked question?

My intuition is that it shouldn't, otherwise this would mean that there is a $q>1$ such that $X\subset L^q(0,1)$. But then if $1\leq n/(n-1)<q$ then $x^{-1+1/n}\in L^q(0,1)$ which I'm guessing is incorrect. But at first glance, it seems that $X$ satisfies the properties.

Comment: do you want to verify $X\subset L^q$ or $X\subset \bigcup_{1<p\leq\infty} L^p$?

Comment: The latter is clear, right? I defined it in such a way to have it.

Comment: the latter seems to be true but I was able to find a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically showed already that there does not exist a $q>1$ such that $X\subset L^q$ holds.

Using the statement from the linked question, this implies that the condition
$$
\tag{*}
X\subset \bigcup_{1<p\leq\infty} L^p(0,1)
$$
is false (if it were true then $X\subset L^q$ would follow for some $q>1$).

You might be falsely thinking that (*) should be correct,
because for all $n\in\Bbb N$ we have $x^{1/n-1}\in L^p$ for some $p>1$.
However, this argument is not sufficient, because we do not have the same statement
for elements in the closure.

For example, consider the element
$$
z := \sum_{n\in\Bbb N} x^{1/n-1} 2^{-n}.
$$
It can be shown that $z\in X\subset L^1(0,1)$ and that $z\not\in L^p(0,1)$ for any $p>1$.

Comment: So this means that it's hard to naively construct such a set $X$!

Comment: @UserA well, you could start with a set $X\subset L^p$ for some $p>1$, but constructing interesting sets $X$ would be hard.